# how do you do a "vertical scale" of a shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, drawing

I need to know how to "vertically scale" a square on Illustrator, and then do a "Horizontal sheer" for a 3D shape but I have no idea what it means or how to do it, if anyone knows I'd appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Ask the person who gave you that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3d effect in a square. Expand the appearance first.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then with the layer selected use Transform window and enter the desired value for Vertical or Horizontal Adjustment.

[image]

[image]

Lastly select the points you want to sheer and Use Sheer tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I"m missing something....

You can just use the Bounding Box to make an object taller (vertical scale). Grab a handle and drag vertically. Or, you can input a Height value in the **Control Bar** or **Transform Panel** to increase and object's height.

Then you can use the **Free Transform** tool to skew the shape. Or again, use the **Transform Panel** to add skew.